# GroupBy with OR composite key not AND composite

Tags: c#, linq

I have a special case, I try to match payments to invoices. I do that with a standard left join.

Now I get a list of payment to invoice. But I need to group it to to validate input.

I need to get a list of invoices connected to a list of payments.

Many payments to one invoiceis ok, but many invoices to many payments are not.

If I do a composite key group like `GroupBy(leftJoin => new { leftJoin.payment.Id, leftJoin.invoice?.Id })` this will not work  it will return same result as the join basicly.

`GroupBy(leftJoin => leftJoin.payment.Id)` this will work in the case of one payment to many invoices. But it will break for many invoics to same payment.

`GroupBy(leftJoin => leftJoin.invoice?.Id)` This works for one invoice to many payments but will group unmatched payments in a group (not a big deal) plus it will break for one payment to many invoices

I need to use a composite key, but it needs to be a OR relation between the keys. Not and, ideas?

Edit: entire method on request

```
public async Task MatchInvoicesWithPaymentsAsync(IEnumerable<InvoiceReadInfo> invoices, IEnumerable<PaymentReadInfo> payments)
    {
        var result = payments
            .SelectMany(p => invoices.Where(i => p.Reference == i.Ocr).DefaultIfEmpty(), (p, i) => new { p, i })
            .GroupBy(leftJoin => leftJoin.p.Id) //<--- problem goes here method GetMatchJob below takes a list of payments and a list of invoices 
            .Select(grp => GetMatchJob(grp.Select(info => info.p).ToList(), grp.Select(info => info.i).Where(i => i != null).Distinct().ToList()))
            .Select(job => _handlers[job.MatchOutcome](job))
            .Where(r => r != null)
            .ToList();

        await ProcessMatches(result);
    }
```

edit: solution after discussion in comments

```
private class GroupByComparer : IEqualityComparer<InvoicePayment>
{
    public bool Equals(InvoicePayment x, InvoicePayment y)
    {
        if (x.Invoice == null ||    y.Invoice == null)      return true;
        if (x.Invoice.InvoiceId ==  y.Invoice.InvoiceId)    return true;
        if (x.Payment.Id ==         y.Payment.Id)           return true;
        
        return false;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(InvoicePayment obj)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is `invoice` nullable?

Comment: If a invoice was not matched to the payment. (left join)

Comment: Then shouldn't those be excluded from the query entirely earlier-on with `.Where( pmt => pmt.invoice != null )` ?

Comment: Is this Linq-to-Objects or Linq-to-Entities?

Comment: We mark these as wrong payments and refund them if we can (if we have enough info about the sender to resend them). Its often a older person that have manually paid money to us from a bank form.

Comment: Please post your full Linq expression tree, including the definition of the type of `leftJoin`.

Comment: This is domain layer, so in memory linq to objects

Comment: i added orignal method

Comment: You may be able to use an overload for `GroupBy` and pass in your own `IEqualityComparer<TKey>` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___0___2__System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer___1__

Comment: Dude, offcourse. You so seldom use them so you forget  about them. I add my solution please write a answer and I accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the overload for `GroupBy` that accepts an `IEqualityComparer<TKey>`.

> Groups the elements of a sequence according to a key selector function. The keys are compared by using a comparer and each group's elements are projected by using a specified function.

[Full documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___0___2__System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer___1__)

You would basically implement something like:

```
public class CompositeGroupingKeyComparer : IEqualityComparer<InvoicePayment>
{
    public bool Equals(InvoicePayment x, InvoicePayment y)
    {
        // Handle your OR logic here        
        return 
            x.Invoice?.InvoiceId == y.Invoice?.InvoiceId || // Not fully convinced by 2 nulls matching though perhaps you need to only match if both sides have an invoice?
            x.Payment.Id == y.Payment.Id;
    }

    // This part is key as you require the grouping to identify the same hash codes and then deal with Equals method.
    public int GetHashCode(InvoicePayment obj)
    {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: My example of IEqualityComparer works fine! Thanks for the idea

Comment: As a side note its important that GetHashCode returns same value otherwise it will not work.

Comment: @Anders Great to hear it helped! It is a very good point you make re: `GetHashCode` and I suspect that it always has to match to allow for the equality comparison to work?

Comment: It does a hashcode check so that it can store the result quickly in for example a dictionary. Should be o(n) complexity. With my solution it will probably be o(n^2) complexity. But a hashcode does not cut it for my use case.